# LINQ to SQL error with id on insert

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq-to-sql, visual-studio-2012

I'm a beginner in `LinQ To SQL` (I'm using Visual Studio 2012 with .NET framework 4). I have generated the dbml file with the O/R designer. From that file I generated the database.

Here is the thing: when I try to insert an Object to the database I get a message (is in spanish) telling me `"Can not insert the value NULL into column 'id'... The column does not allow NULLS. INSERT error".`

The entity (and table) name is "EstadisticaExamen", and (in the dbml) is set to "Auto Generated Value", Auto-Sync = On Insert and Type = int (System.Int32).

The name of the .dbml file is Modelo.

Here is the insertion code:

```
ModeloDataContext dc = new ModeloDataContext();

EstadisticaExamen estadistica = new EstadisticaExamen();

//initialization of fields
dc.EstadisticaExamen.InsertOnSubmit(estadistica);

dc.SubmitChanges();
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you mean the 'id' column is set to "Auto Generated Value", etc.?

Comment: You might want to share the Entity definition and the mapping of the entities.

Comment: In your database, is your Id column is defined as an Identity column?

Answer (score 0):

Define your Id column as an auto-incrementing identity, and then you can pass null in.

Comment: yes but as I have read in this page, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/46422/A-LINQ-Tutorial-Adding-Updating-Deleting-Data, "If your class has an Identity column and is flagged as IsDbGenerated in its Column attribute, then on SubmitChanges(), LINQ to SQL will automatically update that column's value for you to the ID set by the database.

Comment: What that means is your model class will now have the ID assigned by the database. But, the IsDbGenerated property implies that the DB itself is generating the ID, which is why the model needs to grab the ID after it has submitted it. For this reason you need to have the database generate your ID for you, and an identity column is the easiest way to do this.

Comment: yes, you're right! sorry! I have defined the auto-incrementing identity and it works! Thanks a lot!